# compiler doesn't see the first line?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to search and match an input from a text file content, the file content is:

```
Manager
Mohab
123456789
Employee
Sarah
987654321.
```

It doesn't read the 1st line and searching about another user outputs the 2 if conditions!

Here is my code:

```
    cout << "Username : ";
    cin >> usrname;
    cout << "Password : ";
    cin >> password;
    fstream myfile;
    myfile.open("Data.txt");

        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            while ( getline (myfile,line) )
            {
                myfile >> culmn1 >> culmn2 >> culmn3;
                if(usrname==culmn1 && password==culmn2)
                {
                    cout << culmn1 << culmn2 <<culmn3;
                    //cout << "Logedin Successfuly\n" ;
                }
                else cout << "Wrong Username or Password!\n";
            }

            myfile.close();
        }
        else cout << "Unable to open the file!\n";
```

thanks for help in advance :)

Comment: ***compiler*** _doesn't see the first line?_ -- what's the compiler got to do with this problem?

Comment: Side note: never store passwords in plain text in real applications. Always store hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you read the file is incorrect. Like this

```
       while (myfile >> culmn1 >> culmn2 >> culmn3)
        {
            if(usrname==culmn1 && password==culmn2)
```

For some reason you used getline *and* >>, getline read the first line and >> read the second.

Answer (score 2):

This :

```
getline (myfile,line)
```

Will consume a line from the stream `myfile`.